# How can I fix this slick2D hello world program to work with windows 8.1?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I think windows 8.1 is the problem anyway.

I'm using the tutorial on Slick2D's website to create a hello, world program to ensure that my installation of slick went well.

This is the relevant code:

```
        //init stuff
        AppGameContainer appgc;
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game("Simple Slick Game"));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(640, 480, false);
        appgc.start();
        //draw a string that says howdy
        g.drawString("Howdy!", 10, 10);
```

But when I execute it, it looks like this glitchy mess:

[image: Glitchy Window]

The numbers change several times/second.

I think that Slick not supporting win8.1 might be the issue, because this is logged in the console:

```
 WARNING: Found unknown Windows version: Windows 8.1
 Attempting to use default windows plug-in.
```

Other than that, not sure. Maybe an issue with the font? Or some weird utf thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly what is your problem but what you see is "Howdy!" text over the text "FPS 9860".

Try to change the position of Howdy, for example:

```
g.drawString("Howdy!", 100, 100);
```

If you don't want to show the FPS (frames per second) you probably can disabled it but if you are implementing a game or graphic stuff, it is a good info to know when running your program.

Comment: Wowwwww I'm dumb. That worked. I thought I was getting some sort of weird unicode/utf glitch, didn't even think of that. Thanks!

Comment: @user3238865 No problem, all of us made some of this some times ;). If my answer is the correct, please accept it (with the tick under the down vote button).